# ROAuth authentication step when using twitteR

Tags: r, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, rstudio

This is similar to some other questions about this issue, but I'm not finding a fix for my current problem. I have the following code:

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(RCurl)

download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")

requestURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"

accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"

authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"

consumerKey <- "..."
consumerSecret<-"..."

twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                             consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                             requestURL=requestURL,
                             accessURL=accessURL,
                             authURL=authURL)


twitCred$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")

registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)

save(list="twitCred", file="twitteR_credentials")
```

This code works in R, but it isn't working in R studio, I still get TRUE when i run the second last line, but it will not allow me to use the package properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does "not allow me to use the package properly" mean exactly? What is the precise error you are encountering?

Comment: i mean if i try to search for tweets it gives me the error that I am not authorized